# Angular 2 . Read value from ngFor variable to component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a view as follows

```
 <select  class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let program of formList.programs">{{program}}</option>
</select>
```

I would like to assign  the 'program' variable value to another property in my component called 'programvalue'. How can I do that ?

```
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
public programvalue:string;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you assign it in component file itself rather than assign from template?

Comment: Could you please tel me how i can do that.  I want the selected user value to be set to programvalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the value using [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html) inside `select`.

Your .html file should look like:

```
 <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="programvalue">
   <option *ngFor="let program of formList.programs">{{ program }}</option>
 </select>
{{ programvalue }}
```

And your .ts file:

```
export class AppComponent {
 public programvalue: string;

 formList = {
  programs: [
   "Program 1",
   "Program 2",
   "Program 3"
  ]
 }
}
```

[Plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/jgIPDCSAZ8SIo12jCqGD/)